# How do I run react-data-grid examples on jsfiddle?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to get a hang of react-data-grid and the examples on their [page](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/editable) have a "play around with it" link that takes you to jsfiddle. For some reason, I am unable to see the output on jsfiddle. 
What would be a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the dependencies are deprecated in the latest react version used by jsfiddle. On inspecting the resources accessed by their [page](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/editable) and comparing it with fiddle, you can hack a solution by doing the following in jsfiddle :

1. remove `react-with-addons.js` and `react-dom.js` from external resources tab.
2. add [`react.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js) and [`react-dom.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js) in external resources.
3. replace [`jsfiddle-integration-babel.js`](https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js) in script with [`this`](https://reactjs.org/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js).

Try this [`fork`](https://jsfiddle.net/2m40Lteq/). It doesn't update contents in table, which is the same state as in page.