# react-data-grid jsfiddles not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I'm trying for hours and I can't get react-data-grid to running. It must be told that I'm new to react! And in that the documentation is very poor, this is very challenging for me.

If only their jsfiddles would work. None of them do!
I found a thread from end 2017 that asks for the same thing: [How do I run react-data-grid examples on jsfiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923987/how-do-i-run-react-data-grid-examples-on-jsfiddle)

But the accepted answer does not work (anymore). You can test it by yourself.
How am I supposed to do that if I can't even get it to run on jsfiddle.

Can someone please help? It must have to do with the corresponding dependency versions, in my opinion, but I'm not sure.

Thank you.